# aspnet identity avoid simultaneous login same account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-mvc-5.1, asp.net-identity

I was searching but I could not find one answer to this question: does aspnet identity provide one way to avoid simultaneous login from the same account?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Identity does not have a built-in way to track simultaneous logins, but you can do a work-around: every time user logs-in, before setting auth-cookie, change user's `SecurityStamp` by `await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);`

And make sure you have this part in your `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

This way every time user log-in, all other sessions will be invalidated because the SecurityStamp on user is changed. And the `validateInterval` to a low enough value, so other auth-cookies can be invalidated soon enough.

Comment: I was looking for a way to avoid login if exists an active session for that user. UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync would do the trick?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio `GetSecurityStampAsync` will return you only a security stamp which is a GUID stored in user's record - by itself it does not do much. As for avoiding to login second time, it is much more complex - you'll somehow will need to track current session, preserve ID for that, put that ID into auth-cookie and on login check if current session is the same as already stored. And I can foresee a pile of problems with this approach. Ultimately if you want users to stop sharing a login, suggested approach will tech them pretty soon that password sharing is bad.

Comment: await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id),  in which file in MVC 5?

Comment: @trailmax any complete example or step how to do it?

Comment: @Pravin https://tech.trailmax.info/2015/09/prevent-multiple-logins-in-asp-net-identity/